# Building SQL query

Tags: python, django

I wrote a messy function and I am wondering if you see any way I could clean it up.  Essentially it takes in a list `e_1=2&e_2=23&e_3=1` and makes a queryset out of it, maintaining the ordering.

```
from operator import itemgetter
def ids_to_students(items, prefix=0):

    if prefix == 0:
        # Make ordered QuerySets of Students based on there ids
        etuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == 'e_'], key=itemgetter(0))
        ituples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == 'i_'], key=itemgetter(0))
        tuples = etuples+ituples
    else:
        tuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == '%s_'%prefix], key=itemgetter(0))

    pk_list  = [v for (k,v) in tuples]
    clauses   = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
    ordering  = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
    students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra(
                select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
    return students
```

It's called like this:

```
students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items())
e_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'e')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tuples are sorted primarily by the first item of each. If they are all unique, specifying `key=itemgetter(0)` makes no difference.

This code

```
if prefix == 0:
    etuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == 'e_'], key=itemgetter(0))
    ituples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == 'i_'], key=itemgetter(0))
    tuples = etuples+ituples
else:
    tuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == '%s_'%prefix], key=itemgetter(0))
```

can be rearranged like this to avoid repetition:

```
prefixes = ['%s_'%prefix] if prefix else ['e_', 'i_']
tuples = sorted(item for item in items if item[0][:2] in prefixes)
```

Comment: Great improvement! I used your improvement in final code of my answer, hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to logic, which Janne's answer covered, here is some style analysis (which is an important part of writing good code):

First - it's nice to have a good docstring, with all the information about the function - what does it do, what does it take, what it returns.

```
from operator import itemgetter
```

This can be a matter of opinion, but it's a good practice not to import member of a module. So doing `import operator` and calling `operator.itemgetter` in your module might give someone who is reading your code a better idea of where the `itemgetter` is coming from.

```
def ids_to_students(items, prefix=0):
```

Since prefix is a string, it might be more clear to provide default value as `''`.

```
etuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == 'e_'], key=itemgetter(0))
```

Only one space before and after `=`, missing space after comma.

```
tuples = etuples+ituples
```

One space before and after `+` sign.

```
tuples   = sorted([(k,v) for k,v in items if k[:2] == '%s_'%prefix], key=itemgetter(0))
```

This line is longer then 80 characters, which is in most cases a very reasonable limit. Breaking it down into two is a good idea.

```
students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra(
            select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
```

When you break the statement into two lines - indent the second line by the multiple of 4.

And the whole thing (I took the list comprehension from Janne's answer, don't forget to upvote it):

```
def ids_to_students(items, prefix=''):
    """Converts request items into a queryset.

    Usage:
        >>> students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items())
        >>> e_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'e')

    Args:
        items: A dict of request.GET.items().
        prefix: A prefix for DB entries.

    Returns:
        A queryset.
    """
    # Make ordered QuerySets of Students based on their ids.
    prefixes = ['%s_' % prefix] if prefix else ['e_', 'i_']
    tuples = sorted(item for item in items if item[0][:2] in prefixes)

    pk_list = [v for (k, v) in tuples]
    clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
    ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
    students = Student.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra(
            select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering', ))
    return students
```